# Ranger: How to Remap hjkl Keys?

Tags: linux, ranger

I using Ranger and I am a [Colemak Keyboard Layout](https://colemak.com/) user. I want to remap the `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` keys to `n`, `u`, `e`, `i` keys. I tried this: [issue #8](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/8) and Ranger doesn't seem to read from `~/.config/ranger/keys.py`. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` and try changing these lines:

```
copymap <UP>       k
copymap <DOWN>     j
copymap <LEFT>     h
copymap <RIGHT>    l
```